# select element based on nearest ancestor

Tags: html, css

I want to write a CSS code that becomes selected based on the nearest ancestor. For example in this HTML:

```css
.ancestor1 .child {
  color: red;
}

.ancestor2 .child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ancestor1">
  <div class="ancestor2">
    <div>
      <p class="child">Hi</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ancestor2">
  <div class="ancestor1">
    <div>
      <p class="child">Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the second `p` tag(Hello) become red, but it's blue because the `.ancestor2 .child` is become later in CSS file.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I just want to know is it impossible by CSS or not :|

Comment: What do you want to apply in "in this example i want to apply `.ancestor2 .child`" ?

Comment: @Jonjie, something like `background-color`, I want to know how to select it using CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very ambiguous question. Is it really CSS you are pertaining to and not JavaScript?

And if you are pertaining to javascript, it is most likely that this is a duplicate question if not related.

Comment: Yes, I want only use CSS, in `jQuery` there is a function name `closest` that do this, but I want to know is it possible in pure CSS too or not?

Comment: Okay. The answer is no. There is no way to select a parent element in CSS not event in CSS3 specification. You have to resort to JavaScript to achieve this goal. The following are the specs for CSS selectors:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors
- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Comment: if there is no other interesting solution, I'll accept this. thank you.

Comment: Some have already shown you how to achieve that using jQuery. In plain JavaScript: var el = document.querySelector(yourElementHere); el.parentNode;

Answer (score 1):

To do this, the most easy way is to use jQuery. if you use jQuery you can use the function closest. To get the div its closest to you. If this is not the right div call closest to the div that was closest to your child until you get the wanted div. Have a look at: [Closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Sven

Comment: thanks for mention it, but I want a to know is there a pure CSS solution for it too or not.
the javascript solution for my problem is the function you say(closest).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this: *If I understand your question, may be you may try this*

```css
.ancestor1 p.child{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ancestor1">
    <div class="ancestor2">
        <div>
            <p class="child">Hi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OR it is better to use jquery/javascript**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ancestor1').find('.child').css('color', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ancestor1">
    <div class="ancestor2">
        <div>
            <p class="child">Hi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```